# Fluent getters generate errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-14, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a project with the following lombok.config file:

```
lombok.accessors.chain = true
lombok.accessors.fluent = true
```

So the following class should compile fine:

```
@Data class A {
  private int i;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A().i();
  }
}
```

and it does when compiling with javac. But Intellij (with or without the lombok plugin) shows a compilation error and the auto completion suggests using `getI()` which does not exist.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're facing issue [53](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/53).

As a workaround, you could use [`@Accessors`](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors.html):

```
@Accessors(fluent = true) // order matters
@Data
class A {
    private int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().i();
    }
}
```

compile fine here (IntelliJ 14.0.3, lombok-plugin 0.8.9)